# the meaning of !this.get in backbone todo MVC app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Came across the following in the exampl backbone Todo MVC App, and it doesnt make any sense to me, googled around and no dice,

inside the todo model there is this toggle method :

```
// Toggle the `completed` state of this todo item.
toggle: function() {
  this.save({
    completed: !this.get('completed')
  });
}
```

I've always understood the ! to mean 'not', which doesn't make sense to me, as I would assume when firing the toggle event one wants to save the completed status.

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does mean "not", and that's what's doing the actual toggling of the state. The `!` operator is a logical operator in this case, and returns the complementarty boolean value.

The `this.get('completed')` call will get the current state of the `completed` property, for example the value `true`.

The `!` operator will get the complementary value, for example the value `false`.

This value is used to create an object literal, for example `{ completed: false }`.

The object is used in the call to the `save` method, so value in the object is used as the new value for the `completed` property.

Answer (score 2):

Basic principle:
assumed, we have a method, return a boolean state.

```
var state = obj.getState('completed');
```

if `getState` returns `true`, variable `state` is `true` as well

now:

```
var state = !obj.getState('completed');
```

we ***invert*** the result, which means: if  `getState` returns `true`,  variable `state` is set to `false`.

In order to have a toggle like `true - false - true - false`, we can do

```
 a = !a
```

if a is true, it's then false, if it's false, it's then true etc.

Comment: thanks, both great answers, but i chose the other as i think that it answers a little more in context and so may help others who find this question.